# Set birthday for test users

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to change the birthday of the test users with SDK or API?
As I see here, the birthday cannot be modified:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/

Is this true for test users also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true for users also.

Why would the API let test users change their birthday date while normal users can't, since the goal of a test user is to test and automatize normal users' behavior?

Plus, if test users could have their birthday date modified through the API, how would that be useful to you?

Comment: I am trying to create a test app for my facebook app.
Depending on the birthday my facebook app does certain actions and I was trying to test this.

Anyway, thank you for your answer. I'll do the testing some other way.